# ansible how to run playbook on multiple hosts independently?

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible playbook to patch multiple linux servers 100+ hosts.
Sometimes is patching hanged on some host too long...
Is any way how to run this playbook independently on each host, not wait to ohers ?
Currently I  am using settings : `forks = 20`

```
TASK [Patching] **********************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [host1]
changed: [host2]
changed: [host3]
STUCKED HERE
```

after 1hour

```
changed: [host1]
changed: [host2]
changed: [host3]
fatal: [host4]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh
```

why it wait to long to get UNREACHABLE status ?

Answer (score 1):

You might use the `free` strategy.

On the top level of your play add :

```
- hosts: all
  strategy: free
  tasks:
   ...
```

Using this strategy "Ansible will not wait for other hosts to finish the current task before queuing more tasks for other hosts"

See [HERE](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/free_strategy.html#free-strategy) for more informations on the free strategy.

When targeting a high number of hosts it's also a good idea to adopt a rolling method using `serial`. See [HERE](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-batch-size-with-serial) for more information on serial.

Answer (score 0):

You're not suggesting Ansible targets one host at a time are you? By default Ansible will attempt to run on all targeted hosts in parallel, well.. in batches. In your case it should target 20 hosts at a time. It should not wait for the failed job. Or is there something in your configuration which prevents this?

What happens when you run the playbook with the `--forks 100` option?

Also wondering what goes wrong in your patching job causing it to *hang*?

Comment: not hang...but maybe some server causing some nw delay or longer patching ( +1hour) . but from my experience e.g. patching task is waiting until all hosts are processed and then it jumps to next task.

Comment: Oh wow, that is long.. Then you might indeed benefit from using the 'free' strategy option answer.